# resize of image not working in codeigniter 3

Tags: resize, codeigniter-3, image-uploading

I've been attempting to resize a image in codeigniter 3 ,but no luck! I have the resize inside the ddoo_upload() function , the resize() will work , when it comes to one image field within that form and if you will add two image field within that form , then the resize() will not work. Not sure what is wrong!

This is what i have tried for image upload,The code below shows my upload function (and resize within it)

```
if (isset($_FILES['destiimg']) && $_FILES['destiimg']['name'] != '') {
                    $filename = $this->ddoo_upload('destiimg', '2000' , '336');
} else {
                    $filename = NULL;
} 

if (isset($_FILES['destiimg_thumb']) && $_FILES['destiimg_thumb']['name'] != '') {
                    $destbannerthumb_imgnew = $this->ddoo_upload('destiimg_thumb', 300 , 225);
                } else {
                    $destbannerthumb_imgnew = NULL;
                } 








function ddoo_upload($filename, $width, $height)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';  
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($filename)) {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();die();
        return NULL;
    } else {

        $data = $this->upload->data();          
        $filename = $data['file_name'];

        $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config1['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
        //$config1['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config1['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config1['width'] = $width;
        $config1['height'] = $height;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        return $filename;
    }
}
```

The upload works fine , but the resize has some issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some config options when loading `image_lib`.

Look at the [manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html), you didn't specified `source_image` (and other options).

If you want to use something advanced, there is good library called [Image Moo](http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/). It's older but good working with CI3.